# map float to fixed point

Tags: control-systems

I have  designed a system in simulink and works well through simulation. In order to convert to fixed point, I tried fixed point advisor with little success. The reason being that the coefficients on the float model are larger than 1. I have two of them, a1=0.021 and a2= 3600. My input is from an 16 bit ADC (Q15). So how to scale everything within the range -1 to +1?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed point processing is not for the faint of heart. It typically requires managing scaling factors, clipping point, signal to noise ratios, underflow, limit cycles, rounding behavior at each single point of your processing chain.

Your best shot at dealing with different data ranges is to rigorously use the Q-number format for each data, state and coefficient in your processing (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format)) and do the correct multiply & shift  & round/truncate at each operation. This may require statistical or worst case analysis to determine the clipping points and best Qs for each variable.

In order of complexity, you can consider

1. Convert your fixed point data to floating point, run the algorithm in floating point, and then only limit and convert back to fixed point as the last step.
2. Same as item one but if you can't do float consider using 24-bit or 32-bit fixed point data instead. This creates a extra margin and headroom and makes life A LOT easier
3. Stick with 16-bit all around. That means you have to fight for every single dB of signal to noise ratio at every step of your processing. Depending on what you are doing you may consider selectively using double precision for critical state variables or operations.

Answer (score 0):

The OP did not clarify but if this is for purpose of simulating fixed point quantization effects the following mapping would be simplest and sufficient:

For the floating point number given as $x$ scaled to be in the range of -1 to +1, and fixed point number as $\hat x$, and number of bits $b$, the signed fixed point can be represented as integers in the range of $-2^{b-1} to +2^{b-1}-1$ by doing the following:

$$ \hat x= \text{round} \bigg(\frac{x + 1}{2} (2^b-1)\biggr)- 2^{b-1}$$

So in the OP's case, the coefficients a1 and a2 would first be scaled to be in the range of +1 to -1 by normalizing by the largest coefficient (assuming no further scaling is needed to prevent subsequent overflow, which is often better done for noise considerations by increasing precision with extended precision accumulators and then scaling back down at the end):

$$\hat a_1 = \text{round} \bigg(\frac{0.021/3600 + 1}{2} (2^{16}-1)\biggr)- 2^{15} = 688 $$

$$\hat a_2 = \text{round} \bigg(\frac{3600/3600 + 1}{2} (2^{16}-1)\biggr)- 2^{15} = 2^{15}-1 = 32767 $$

Further mapping can be performed from the fixed point integer representations derived above if different binary representation is needed such as 2's complement etc but for purpose of further simulation the above is simplest to use as a signed integer. As is commonly done, the above includes a 1/2 bit offset since the magnitude of the negative number is larger than the positive number. This is typically of no consequence, but if there was any concern with this it can be eliminated by adding half a bit to the final result.

Comment: So are you proposing data type to be integer rather than fractional one? and what is the source of the conversion formula you proposed?

Comment: The choice of integer vs fractional comes down to convenience to your subsequent use  (the tool or application where you’ll use it)- either can be used as to get fractional values is just scaling. The formula is just mapping the floating point numbers in a range of +/-1 to the integers over the number of bits given.

Comment: I did not quite understand how the ratio has been taken for a1 and a2

Comment: I had simply assumed you wanted to maximize your dynamic range with a2 as your largest number (which is why I made the comment about being careful nothing further would be larger). Otherwise use your largest number you think you may ever have as the denominator. (So in this case I made 3600 positive full scale, corresponding to your +1). What is the purpose of what your doing? Is it for a fixed point implementation (which Hilmar's answer would be more applicable) or are you just simulating the quantization effects of going to fixed point (which my answer would be more applicable)

Comment: Thank you. I got it.